# Back navigation using browser back button not working

Tags: ionic2

I implemented a *tabs with side menu* interface as seen on https://www.djamware.com/post/587d543080aca723c115beaf/how-to-mixing-side-menu-and-tabs-in-ionic-2. Things are working well as it was inteded from the tutorial except for an issue. Take this example:

1. User is on Tab1.
2. User decides to navigate to Tab2, clicks Tab2.
3. User wants to navigate BACK to Tab1, clicks previous button on Chrome.

**ISSUE:** User is not able to navigate back when previous/back button is clicked, instead the url changes but the active Tab does not.

Back button works for all pages except on tabbed pages.

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="myIndex">
<ion-tab tabIcon="home" [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab tabIcon="timer" [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Schedules"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab tabIcon="briefcase" [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Cases"></ion-tab>
```

**tabs.ts**

```
 @IonicPage()
        @Component({
        selector: 'page-tabs',
        templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
        })
export class TabsPage {
        tab1Root= 'HomePage';
        tab2Root= 'SchedulePage';
        tab3Root= 'CasesPage';
        myIndex: number;
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
      }
    }
```

The repo I am working on is at https://github.com/jjjhanreyyy/Prosecutor-App

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Mainly, you want to have the relevant code here in the question, not on some link that will die any moment. Tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, say what result you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
})
```

change it to

```
@IonicPage({
  segment: 'page-tabs'
})
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
```

This is derived from this Github [repo](https://github.com/kensodemann/test-bed-tabs).